# Preferred recoverable method to store passwords in database

Tags: database, encryption, password-encryption

I want to store some passwords on my database at server.

The passwords should be recoverable, since I want to use them for a third-party api which needs the password. (So I can't use one-way methods like md5...)

What is the best method to save passwords in database? Isn't there any better way than storing plain text?

Comment: You can encrypt them, but that only shifts the problem to storing the master key.

Comment: And placing the master key on another database, to avoid SQL Injection attacks, maybe??

Comment: md5 is a broken one-way method... just for the record.

Comment: @EricJ. That's a misleading statement in this context. The reason why md5 isn't fit for password hashing is its speed, and not its broken collision resistance. Plain SHA-2 would be almost as bad.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: *it has since been shown that MD5 is not collision resistant* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5, reference http://merlot.usc.edu/csac-f06/papers/Wang05a.pdf

Comment: @EricJ. I know. But that's irrelevant in this context. We only require first pre-image resistance. Of course one would avoid it, because confidence in MD5's pre-image resistance is lower than for modern hashes. The important points for password hashing are a high number of iterations and a salt. Choice of primitive is secondary.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I agree that salt + many iterations makes the choice secondary.  Still, why begin with a cryptographically weaker hash algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes.aspx) is cryptographically sound and probably the most common encryption (as opposed to hashing) mechanism selected for new applications.

Take care to generate a random initialization vector (IV) for each password that you encrypt, and store the Key and the IV separately from the encrypted password bytes.

To understand differences between AES and Rijndael check out

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2006/10/09/the-differences-between-rijndael-and-aes.aspx

> there are some differences between Rijndael and the official FIPS-197 specification for AES

You should use a unique IV per user. However, storing the key-per-user makes for a complex key management scenario. I would suggest one key for the application and an IV per user.

The IV can be saved alongside the ciphertext. The key should be stored outside of the database.

You could store the key, encrypted, in web.config. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200/encrypting-appsettings-in-web-config).

Comment: You should use a unique IV per user.  However, storing the key-per-user makes for a complex key management scenario.  I would suggest one key for the application and an IV per user.

Comment: Storing the IV separately from the ciphertext is unusual. Prepending the IV to the ciphertext is standard.

Comment: And where should I save each IV? (in another database for avoid SQL Injection attacks? or ...)

Comment: The IV can be saved alongside the ciphertext.  The key should be stored outside of the database.

Comment: And where should I store the Key? inside code? in a file? in web.config? in another database? or ...?

Comment: You could store the key, encrypted, in web.config.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200/encrypting-appsettings-in-web-config

Comment: Thanks, and can you please put these information (that you provided in comments) in your answer text?

Comment: A problem: I can't use that command-line tool, since I'm using a Shared Hosting. What should I do?

Comment: Have a look at the options here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349130/encrypting-web-config-on-shared-hosting

Comment: Which one should I use? Rijndael or AES??

Comment: If you contract for the US government or a Fortune 1000 company, probably AES as it is FIPS compliant.  Otherwise either will be fine.